# Cannot enable sound when building from source

Tags: osx, build

I can't seem to enable sound support when building Emacs from source:

> Does Emacs support sound?                               no

It does not seem to be doing anything even if I do:

> ./configure --with-sound=yes

Looking at more of the output I see the lines:

> checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
>   checking for sys/soundcard.h... no

I'm using macOS 10.13 with the latest version of Emacs.

Does this mean that Emacs cannot see/access my soundcard? My computer works fine with sound by the way.

Here is the configuration output after running ./configure:

```
Configured for 'x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0'.

  Where should the build process find the source code?    .
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             no
    (The GNU allocators don't work with this system configuration.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    nextstep
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          none
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                NONE
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   NONE
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  no
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  no
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           no 
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           no 
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use cairo?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -llcms2?                                 yes
  Does Emacs use imagemagick (version 6)?                 no
  Does Emacs support sound?                               no
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  no
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               no
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes (kqueue)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    yes 
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               no
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                yes
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lsystemd?                               no
  Does Emacs use -ljansson?                               no
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                no
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
  Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
  Does Emacs have threading support in lisp?              yes
```

Any help to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Other than an occasional beep (e.g., beginning of buffer, or ending of buffer), I've never heard Emacs generate sound on OSX ...  What types of sounds do you expect to hear?  You can download a pre-built binary for OSX and see/hear what it generally should do:  https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: Hi. One of the packages I plan to use (pomidor.el) seems to need sound output as it generates the warning: Warning (emacs): This Emacs binary lacks sound support.

Although  now that you mention it, i do hear beeps. So I guess the backend for the package I am using just needs a specific program to play sound?

Comment: It looks like someone has already been there and done that and has written a workaround for OSX with a library called `play-sound.el`:  https://github.com/leoliu/play-sound-osx  I recommend trying it by placing `play-sound.el` in your `load-path` and execute the snippet mentioned in the `readme.md` file and see if it works to your satisfaction.  I found that by looking at line 108 of `pomidor.el` https://github.com/TatriX/pomidor/blob/master/pomidor.el#L108 and I got there by search for `start-process`, since that is what is normally used to execute an external application .... I also grepped

Comment: Ah! This seems to be the solution. I'll give it a check and update this question with an answer if it works. Thanks!